# Countablity of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why do we choose Natural number to describe whether a set is countable or not? How can we say that Natural Number is countable?

Comment: That's the definition of countability...

Comment: To answer your second question, the set of natural numbers is countable because the identity function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection.

Comment: The smallest infinite cardinal is the countable infinity.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special role of the naturals is that their cardinality is the smallest that is not finite. That this cardinality bears the special name "countable" is of course owed to the fact that we use the naturals for counting :)

Answer (score 0):

It's just the definition. Cardinality is the size of the set - meaning the number of elements in the set. When we count the elements we call the first element number one, the second number two etc. 
So we use the natural numbers for counting and hence it's called a countable set.

E.g. when you decide for example that the integers have the same cardinality as the natural numbers, you decide by giving each integer a corresponding natural number *you count them using the natural numbers.*